# NodeJS piping with ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I wanted to do a HTTP live stream on a screen cast with using ffmpeg, nodejs and html5 . I wanted it to be as real time as possible. However, I find that my video received by the client was behind by 1~2 seconds (On Chrome/Chromium). I am using vp8/webm as my codec.

I have eliminated the following factors as such:
1) Network: I have tried serving and receiving the video file locally by stating the video source to be 127.0.0.1:PORT or localhost:PORT 

2) ffmpeg encoding speed:I have tried outputting the file locally, it the "delay" seems to be negligible.

3) Chrome internal buffer. The buffer was accounted to be 0.07s~0.08s. 

On the nodeJS side, I have a child process that runs the ffmpeg command, and did a ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(res); <-- ffmpeg is child_process.spawn(...)

So it seems that the ffmpeg.std.pipe(res) of nodejs seems to be the one delaying the video stream. Am  I correct in assuming so ? Is there anyway that I may reduce the delay ?

Comment: 1-2 seconds for this type of application is amazingly low latency.  It's unlikely to get much better than that.  There are buffers at every layer.

Comment: Ahhhh I see... that's... sad for me =(. Thanks Brad !

Answer (score 0):

Go to WebRTC no need to implement any thing like codec,pipe,etc(already in chrome,opera,firefox)

Uses:
MediaCaptureAPI(access your cam and mic and convert object  to URL, default they are using vp8 codec,etc)

RTCPeerconnectionAPI(send and receive media stream p2p)

RTCDatachannelAPI(send and receive data using p2p)

Comment: Hmmm... don't think it will work... Because I want to stream a remote machine's screen to a browser. Please correct me if I'm wrong, WebRTC only enables me to do it from browser to browser (And it seems to be only for video cam and mic). 
Can't use the usual VNC due to some limitations of VNC... =\

Comment: WebRTC also support screen sharing(only in chrome) but it require HTTPS here https://simpl.info/screencapture/

Comment: Oooo webRTC is able to grab screens from the system desktop/windows that are not running in chrome ? Wow... Amazing. I'll try that ! Thank you!